# ajax success: Function()

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax

I am using this Function:

```
function ProcessToken(token) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "HomePage.aspx/ProcessCard",
        data: '{Token: "' + token + '" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        failure: Failure,            
        success: function(R) {     

            var response = R.d
            alert(response)
            if (response = true) {
                alert("True")
                $form.find('.subscribe').html('Payment successful <i class="fa fa-check"></i>');
            } else {
                    alert("False")
                    $form.find('.subscribe').html('Try again').prop('disabled', false);
                    $form.find('.payment-errors').text('Something went wrong, please try again.');
                    $form.find('.payment-errors').closest('.row').show()
            }              

        }

    });

}
```

This is what im trying to return

```
    <WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function ProcessCard(ByVal Token As String) As Boolean
    Return False
End Function
```

I have not been able to get the else statement to occur even though the first alert(response) does show false. The if (response = true) always shows alert("True"). Im not very good at java so not sure how to read the response properly. Ive tried datatype: "text" as well.

Im wanting to make sure true or false is read properly in the if else statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use javascript comparison operators == or === in your if statement:

```
if (response === true) {
 ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you, im native to vb and so used to a single =